# Dynamic Jquery Splitter Plugin

Tags: jquery, split, jquery-ui-resizable

I am trying to use Jquery Splitter http://www.methvin.com/jquery/splitter/

It works fine  if the splitter panes are static but I need to add panes dynamically in it.
Also I need to remove those panes dynamically as well.
How can I remove the splitter binding and add dynamic split regions in it?

please check it from here http://01webdesigner.com/Inam/SplitterTest.htm

Re-sizing works only in the last dynamically added region.

please help

Comment: http://www.methvin.com/jquery/splitter/ is down

Comment: It seems that https://github.com/mo-gr/jQuery-Splitter is the most recent fork.

Comment: https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.splitter to get latest jquery-splitter related updates

Answer (score 15):

jQuery UI layout: http://layout.jquery-dev.net/

Ideas taken from EXT layout model.

Demo: http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos.html

Comment: I've been looking for an alternative to jqxsplitter cause I don't like its cloning portion and this is perfect thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Splitter plugin: http://krikus.com/js/splitter/

- can collapse
- min/max size
- nice
- works