# jquery splitter change to vertical splitter on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a splitter that works fine. Now the client wants to change the splitter from horizontal view to vertival view. I mean that the splitter is first split int the 2 divs horizontally and when I click the button it will change so that it's split the same 2 divs vertically.

I tried this

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $('.LeftPane').attr('id', 'LeftPane');
        $('.RightPane').attr('id'`enter code here`, 'RightPane');
        $("#MySplitter").splitter({
            type: "v"
        });
        $('#Button1').click(function () {
            $('#LeftPane').attr('id', 'TopPane');
            $('#RightPane').attr('id', 'BottomPane');
            $("#MySplitter").splitter({
                type: "h"
            });
        });
    });
    </script>

<style type="text/css" media="all">
   #MySplitter
    {
        height: 400px;
        width: 600px;
        margin: 1em 2em;
        background: #def;
        border: 2px solid #039; /* No padding allowed */
    }
   #LeftPane
    {
        background: #def;
        overflow: auto;
        width: 200px; /* optional, initial splitbar position */
        min-width: 50px; 
    }

    #RightPane
    {
        background: #def;
        overflow: auto;
        min-width: 100px; /* No margin or border allowed */
    }

   #MySplitter .vsplitbar
    {
        width:8px;
        cursor: e-resize; /* in case col-resize isn't supported */
        cursor: col-resize;
        background-color:Black;
    }
    #MySplitter .vsplitbar.active, #MySplitter .vsplitbar:hover
    {
         background-color:Black;
    }


     #TopPane
    {
       background: #def;
        overflow: auto;
        width: 200px; 
        min-width: 50px; /
    }

    #BottomPane
    {
       background: #def;
        overflow: auto;
        min-width: 100px; /* No margin or border allowed */
    }

     #MySplitter .hsplitbar
    {
        height: 2px;
        background: #487BA4;
    }
    #MySplitter .hsplitbar.active, #MySplitter .hsplitbar:hover
    {
        background: #487BA4;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="MySplitter">
    <div class="LeftPane">
        <p>
            This is the left side of the vertical splitter.</p>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="RightPane">
         This is the right side of the vertical splitter.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<p>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="splitchange" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What sorts of results did you get with your sample code?  In what way did it not do what you wanted it to do?

Comment: by defalt spliter split horizontally .when we click on button it divs splits vertically

Comment: Yes.  I know what you want it to do.  That's not the question.  You've given us a large block of sample code (and that's good).  The question is what the sample code actually does.  Presumably, if your sample code actually did what you wanted it to do, you wouldn't be here.

Comment: no my code did not meet my requirments you just dont need to view my code just provide me solution by providing me sample code i will be very thank full to for that.

Comment: One more time... *How* did it not meet your requirements?  What did it do instead?  Did you get an error?  Did it not do anything?  What are the actual effects of the sample code you have provided?

Comment: it provides me wrong results. i am again saying that leave that code just provide my solution please

Comment: My guess from looking at your code would be that the version of splitter you're using cannot be cancelled.  You need to cancel the vertical version before you can apply the horizontal.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611878/dynamic-jquery-splitter-plugin might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at last i find the solution of my onw question.
I am designing it in asp.net so i am providing the solution in jquery with asp.net

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../Js/js/splitter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
enter code here
 <style type="text/css" media="all">
  #MySplitter
  {
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 1em 2em;
    background: #def;
    border: 2px solid #039;
}
```

#LeftPane
    {
        background: #def;
        overflow: auto;
        width: 200px; 
        min-width: 50px; 
    }

```
#RightPane
{
    background: #def;
    overflow: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

#MySplitter .vsplitbar
    {
        width:8px;
        cursor: e-resize; 
        cursor: col-resize;
        background-color:Black;
    }

```
#MySplitter .vsplitbar.active, #MySplitter .vsplitbar:hover
{
     background-color:Black;
}


 #TopPane
{
   background: #def;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 200px; 
    min-width: 50px; 
}

#BottomPane
{
   background: #def;
    overflow: auto;
    min-width: 100px; 
}

 #MySplitter .hsplitbar
{
    height: 2px;
    background: #487BA4;
}
#MySplitter .hsplitbar.active, #MySplitter .hsplitbar:hover
{
    background: #487BA4;
}
</style>


 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         // var result = function () {
        // alert('fired');
       var val =  $('#<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>').val();
         if (val == 1) {
             $('.LeftPane').attr('id', 'LeftPane');
             $('.RightPane').attr('id', 'RightPane');

             $("#MySplitter").splitter({
                 type: "v"
             });
         }
         else {
             $('#LeftPane').attr('id', 'TopPane');
             $('#RightPane').attr('id', 'BottomPane');
             $(' #MySplitter .vsplitbar').css('width', '');
             $("#MySplitter").splitter({
                 type: "h"
             });
         }
         // }
     });
</script>

</head>
<body>
 <form runat="server" >
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server"  Value="1"/>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="change" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

 <div id="MySplitter">
    <div class="LeftPane">
        <p>
            This is the left side of the vertical splitter.</p>
        <p>
            Note what happens when you move the splitbar as far left as you can to make this
            pane very thin. A scrollbar appears and it is flush against the splitbar, just the
            way it should be.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="RightPane">
        <p>
            The splitbar needs to be wide enough to grab with the mouse, but a thick splitbar
            may be visually distracting in a design. This example shows how to make a splitbar
            that looks skinny but has a wider grabbing area. It also demonstrates the use of
            an alternate resize cursor. (Not all browsers support alternate cursors and only
            IE seems to support animated cursors.)</p>
        <p>
            A background image in the splitbar provides the visual marker but the splitbar area
            extends further right, appearing as padding on the right pane. The splitbar's hot
            zone is "biased" to the right so that it will not have a gap against any left-side
            scrollbar when it appears. If you know the left pane will never have a scroll bar,
            you could make the hot zone centered on the skinny splitbar.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Code behind for button is as follows

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HiddenField1.Value == "2")
        {
            HiddenField1.Value = "1";
        }
        else
        {
            HiddenField1.Value = "2";
        }
    }
```